# Como criar chave composta e garantir a mesma propriedade em 2 model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho 3 model

```
public class UnidadeNegocio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeNegocioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set;}
}
public class Venda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeNegocioId { get; set; }

    public float Valor{ get; set; }
}
```

Preciso garantir que na tabela Cliente e Venda, ambas contenham o mesmo Id da Unidade de Negócio. Ou seja, devem ser iguais.

Em Sql server, criamos chave composta

Como eu poderia criar e resolver este problema usando `Fluent Api` do `Entity Framework?`

Comment: Vendo assim as duas tabelas Cliente e Venda, o Cliente 12 sempre será uma UnidadeNegocioId = 1, para que jogar na tabela de Venda, não tem um erro de planejamento ai não ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic isso é um exemplo, ID é sempre dinamico, por isso existe a tabela UnidadeNeogicio

Comment: é um exemplo ruim, porque se você transportar a ID em conjunto que não garante que eu possa mudar na tabela de cliente? ou seja, acredito que isso seja um exemplo ruim.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic é um exemplo visual apenas, para ter um valor "1" como exemplo... Não é exemplo de código, e sim visual...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei a pergunta, removi o "exemplo", pode ajudar?

Comment: Marcelo a tabela estão do mesmo jeito. Para acontecer isso você precisa de uma terceira tabela que contenha um Identificação unica para o Cliente 1 e UnidadeNegocioId = 1 por exemplo e na tabela de Venda trazer esse ID gerado tipo ClienteUnidadeNegocio com 3 campos Id, ClienteId e UnidadeNegocioId ... talvez eu faria assim, depende de um contexto, mas, de inicio seria isso.